# Did lord buddha preach not to get angry even if a leg is cut?

Tags: personal-practice, reference-request, the-buddha, pali-canon, patience

Has lord Buddha preached not to get angry even if limbs are cut if you are a real follower of me? If so, please quote from the relevant sutta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supreme Buddha said that even if someone were to cut you to pieces with a two-handed saw, if you got angry you wouldn’t be a true disciple of his -- [Kakacupama Sutta: The Simile of the Saw, MN 21](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.021x.than.html):

> “Dear Monks, if a person does not get angry or form a hateful mind even when he is dragged, placed upside down, moved his legs to sides, and cut with a saw, he is indeed a disciple who recalls my advice.”

In [this Dhamma article](http://mahamevnawa.lk/do-not-be-afraid-of-merit/) the Mahamevnawa Theravada Buddhist Monastery once elaborated on this as:

> Thus the Supreme Buddha always preached and praised about living free of hatred. He preached that there is one circumstance in which a person cannot realize the Dhamma; that is when the Sangha is not peaceful. If the Sangha is not peaceful or someone acts to break their unity/peace, then one cannot practice the Dhamma since they blame each other. They blame one another saying that each person is wrong. In such situation, they cannot recall the Dhamma and instead they accumulate bad karma. These unwholesome deeds bring great misfortune. So remember that a hatred is formed in a person when he is either in an office, a house, a temple, or in any other place, it is not for the good of any person at all. It is a universal truth. It is because hatred never ends any quarrel. It is ended by not being hateful. It is a universal Dhamma. This Dhamma of the Supreme Buddha is a universal truth. What is this Dhamma? It is the spreading of loving-kindness. Ending hatred by not being hateful (a universal truth). The Supreme Buddha’s Dhamma is no longer exists in India where the Buddha’s Dhamma was born. What is the reason for the Dhamma to disappear from India? It is the hatred that formed in that time. As a result of hatred that formed in the people at that time, they argued and disgraced and insulted on each other. They further used governmental power for that. This resulted in hatred. Hatred is the reason for the Gautama Supreme Buddha’s Dhamma to vanish from India. Therefore, we should not practice to hate for one another. We shall spread our loving-kindness to all beings in all ten directions. One first spread loving-kindness to oneself and not give into being hateful. He dislikes to be angry or hateful and get rid of it quickly. He frees himself from hateful mind and practices the loving-kindness mind.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for finding the source. At times I copy only parts of what I read and not the full article. Also one of these days I have to learn how you get them in 'blue color' in shorten form (hyperlinking?).